# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Heathrow?

Tags: usa, uk, india, layovers, transit-visas

I am an Indian national. I am travelling from the US to India and my flight has a layover at Heathrow Airort London. The layover time is 5h 45 minutes. Even though I do not intend to leave the airport during this layover, do I still need the transit visa?

Comment: Not a dupe of the 'visit' question

Comment: You don't need visa if you are inside airport.